# Nested Serializer not Working with Boolean Values

Tags: django-rest-framework

So I have a nested user settings serializer in my user detail serializer which is working fine unless I provide the nested serializer with false values. If I try to call the update function in my ModelViewSet with a PUT-request with both of the settings with false values, the user settings field is being set to null I guess since I'm getting the following error: "user_settings": "This field is required." This issue only occurs with the HTML-form in the DRF browsable API. Manually setting the fields to false in the JSON works fine. I also want to keep the user settings required.

## User Settings Serializer

```
class UserSettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserSettings
        fields = [
            "allow_marketing_email",
            "allow_notifications"
        ]
```

## User Detail Serializer

```
class UserDetailSerializer(UserSerializer):
    user_settings = UserSettingsSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta(UserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = [
            ...,
            "user_settings"
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_settings_data = validated_data.pop("user_settings")

        ...

        instance.save()

        user_settings = instance.user_settings

        user_settings.allow_marketing_email = user_settings_data.get(
            "allow_marketing_email",
            user_settings.allow_marketing_email
        )

        user_settings.allow_notifications = user_settings_data.get(
            "allow_notifications",
            user_settings.allow_notifications
        )

        user_settings.save()

        return instance
```

Comment: Could it be a bug in the browsable API? Can you confirm that the serializer gets the entire data?

Comment: @Nache Might be... I found a solution around this however by adding a new non-boolean property to my user settings so now they are updated every time.

Comment: can i see your models?